# Discrepancy with volume of two differently generated finite element meshes

Tags: finite-element-method

Can anyone explain the following behavior?  I create a mesh on a `Disk` in two different ways.  First I do it in one step with `ToElementMesh`.  Then, in two steps using `ToBoundaryMesh` followed by `ToElementMesh`.  Why are the total areas so different?

Seems like the indirect method introduces errors of a first order mesh, even though the order in both cases is 2.

Thanks!

```
In[201]:= mesh1 = ToElementMesh[Disk[]];

In[194]:= Pi - Total[mesh1["MeshElementMeasure"], 2]

Out[194]= 2.00118*10^-6

In[202]:= bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[Disk[]];

In[203]:= mesh2 = ToElementMesh[bmesh];

In[197]:= Pi - Total[mesh2["MeshElementMeasure"], 2]

Out[197]= 0.00908652

In[200]:= mesh1["BoundaryElements"] == mesh2["BoundaryElements"]

Out[200]= True
```

Comment: Not to mention `mesh1["PointElements"] == mesh2["PointElements"]`

Comment: @aardvark2012, those are just the IDs of the node coordinates and it does not say anything about how similar a mesh is. Look at the mesh coordinates instead.

Comment: @user21 Ah, yes. Of course. My mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most importantly I'd like to recommend to take a look at the [Element Mesh Generation tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html). That tutorial explains mesh generation for numerical applications like the Finite Element Method and covers you question. If anything is unclear there let me know and it can be improved.

I'll try do give a different explanation than given in the tutorial next. Let's consider for a minute that we have a boundary element mesh like the following:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> {
{1., 0.}, {0.9125378206934781, 0.4089923297618155},{0.6654505497212123, 0.7464419373774067}, {0.32914518683708227,  0.9442793262493796}, {2.8415758474179748*^-8, 0.9999999999999996}, {-0.40899232976181543, 0.9125378206934781}, {-0.7464419373774067, 0.6654505497212122}, {-0.9442793262493796, 0.3291451868370823}, {-0.9999999999999996, 2.8415758313367482*^-8}, {-0.9125378206934783, -0.40899232976181493}, {-0.6654505497212126, -0.7464419373774064}, {-0.3291451868370832, -0.9442793262493793}, {-2.841576059504587*^-8, -0.9999999999999996}, {0.40899232976181327, -0.9125378206934791}, {0.7464419373774028, -0.6654505497212166}, {0.9442793262493757, -0.3291451868370933}}, 
"BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 9}, {9, 10}, {10, 11}, {11, 12}, {12, 13}, {13, 14}, {14, 15}, {15, 16}, {16, 1}}]}];
```

When we pass that to `ToElementMesh` it will generate a full mesh that approximates the boundary given. `ToElementMesh` has no way of knowing what the original input to `ToBoundaryMesh` was when it is given a boundary mesh representation.

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];
```

So how well does `ToElementMesh` approximate `bmesh`? We can not really tell because we do not know what `bmesh` is.

Now, I am telling you that `bmesh` is supposed to represent a `Disk[]`. Then and only then we can check:

```
Pi - Total[mesh["MeshElementMeasure"], 2]
0.0819661
```

And it is a poor presentation. If you do have a symbolic representation of your region it's a good idea to pass that along. That is what `ToNumericalRegion` is for. Let's look at an example. This generates a numerical region of a `Disk[]`:

```
nr = ToNumericalRegion[Disk[]];
```

We can now 'fill in' a boundary mesh like so:

```
bem2 = ToBoundaryMesh[nr, "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> .5, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 1]
```

These options are in fact the ones I used to generate the above example boundary mesh. Note that now the `NumericalRegion` has a boundary mesh - the same as `bem2`

```
bem2 === nr["BoundaryMesh"]
True
```

When you pass the numerical region to `ToElementMesh` things are very different as now `ToElementMesh` has access to the boundary representation and the symbolic representation of the region and can thus generate a better mesh.

```
mesh2 = ToElementMesh[nr];
Pi - Total[mesh2["MeshElementMeasure"], 2]
3.893310501545955`*^-6
```

When you call

```
ToElementMesh[Disk[]]
```

then `ToElementMesh` does have access to the symbolic region. In fact internally, it generates a `NumericalRegion` just as in this post and proceeds like shown here.

You can also set a (boundary) mesh to a `NumericalRegion`:

```
SetNumericalRegionElementMesh[nr, bmesh]
mesh2 = ToElementMesh[nr]
Pi - Total[mesh2["MeshElementMeasure"], 2]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful reply.  

The very last comment is exactly what I need.  I understand that this function SetNumericalRegionElementMesh can pass the information that allows ToElementMesh to construct a good representation of something like a disk.  

The information contained in a boundary mesh is insufficient.

The tutorial you mention does not seem to cover SetNumericalRegionElementMesh.  This seems to provide the functionality needed to create an element mesh with a custom boundary mesh -- which was the problem that motivated my question.  So that was indeed helpful!

Comment: @Will.Mo, `SetNumericalRegionElementMesh` is actually in the mentioned tutorial. Look for the section called 'Numerical Regions'. Since `SetNumericalRegionElementMesh` is there only as program code, it might not be searchable in a browser. It is, however, searchable in the tutorial notebook under  FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation. If you have other suggestions for improvement, let me know.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.  Thanks for the tips, and thanks for teaching me how to search the Mathematica tutorials correctly :).

Comment: @Will.Mo, I must admit that when I searched for it on the web page I did not find it either only when I wanted to add it to the tutorial I did see that I had already done it.... haha. Out of curiosity and if you can say, what are you working on?

Comment: my project involves solving an elliptic PDE with an "oblique boundary condition".  I've managed to get something that works for the "regular" case (where the direction of the derivative is nowhere tangential to the boundary) and now I'm working on the irregular case, and I believe I will need a bit more control with the boundary mesh.

Comment: @Will.Mo, sounds interesting. Maybe at some point you can share your insights?

Comment: Yes, once I figure it out, I'd be happy to share what I came up with -- is stackexchange the right forum for that?

Comment: will do!  thanks again for the help